# Removing each String between two strings and occuring after a specific string

Tags: java, string

I have a String in Java :

style="hello World">One-time meetings< style=\"Hello Again"> stop "Hello"
[image: Sample Input]
I want to remove all the strings that are between " ", occurring immediately after each occurrence of the String "Style".

So, after the removal, the above String will look like :

style="">One-time meetings< style=\""> stop "Hello"

~Thanks

Comment: Sorry. I could not post the HTML code, so modified it now.

Comment: Parse through string and delete everything after a quotation mark until another one is met?

Comment: @Navchetan I suggested an edit that could help you out with the formatting.  (Put your Strings between `backticks` and they'll appear as they are)

Comment: Why there's a escape character after the second 'style'?

Comment: @waltersu OP's struggling to get the formatting of the question right.

Comment: @waltersu  Its part of the HTML code. But i guess that does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove *all* strings that are between the quotes in the `style` attribute then a simple `replaceAll()` should do the trick:

```
String input = "style=\"hello World\">One-time meetings< style=\"Hello Again\"> stop \"Hello\"";
input = input.replaceAll("style=\"(.*?)\"", "style=\"\"");
```

**Update:**

From inspecting your raw input, it appears that the quotes inside the `<style>` tags themselves are already escaped by a single backslash.  If this be the case, then the following replacement should give you what you want:

```
String input = "style=\\\"hello World\\\">One-time meetings< style=\\\"Hello Again\\\"> stop \"Hello\"";
input = input.replaceAll("style=\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\"", "style=\\\\\"\\\\\"?");
```

Comment: I have a big HTML file,  and this code is not working for that.              <p><b style=\"font-size: 10.5pt;\">Recurring meetings</b>                    <br>These meetings also have a unique meeting ID . <b>To create this type of session, you can select &quot;Occurs multiple times&quot; while scheduling your meeting. </b></p>            </li><li>                <p><b style=\"font-size: 10.5pt;\">Instant meetings</b>

Comment: Saying `not working` doesn't let me help you.  What is happening which you should not expect?  Keep in mind that if you have defects in your data (e.g. broken tags, typos), then my solution may not work.

Comment: I understand.  Well its a bigger JSON file with HTML tag etc in it. Which i have no control over.  But, the style=\"SomeString "  multiple pattern is always there.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?  Does the replacement work anywhere?

Comment: I uploaded snippet of the input JSON text that I am parsing. I highlighted the occurrences of "style".  Please take a look.   I tried your code but it is not working with any occurrence of "style"

Comment: Wait...does your raw data actually escape the quotes in `style`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114494/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-navchetan).

Comment: Yes, in my RAW data I do this before running your code :   replaceAll("\\\\n", "");

Answer (score 1):

I think that [parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/342852).
Please use a parser, like [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/)

Example code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select(".style").attr("style", null);
String htmlWithoutStyle = doc.outerHtml();
```

Comment: Parsing a DOM tree with regex is really bad... this is the best answer